# Issues with website migration to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, hosting, dsn

I have an issue migrating one website from my old shared hosting provider to Google Cloud Platform. I followed the same steps for 4 websites, and 3 of them work without issues (.com and .net domains), but with one I have issues (.cf domain). When I open this website in Chrome it doesn't load images, and when I open it in Firefox, it's not secured (SSL). I'm using Cloudflare CDN on all of them.

When I go on dnschecker.org, I see Google's DNS and Cloudflare's too (depending on if I switched it on or off in Cloudflare's dashboard), so that's fine.

I did install the SSL certificate, like for the other 3 websites too. This is the website, so you can check out how it loads:

[ifatw.cf](http://ifatw.cf/)

I used this command to install the certificate, using SSH console:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
```

I even tried changing this in the wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

to this:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.ifatw.cf/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.ifatw.cf/');
```

but that only got me the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error, and I couldn't load my website.

Any ides what's the issue here?

EDIT: This is what I get from the #Curl -I:

```
~$ curl -I ifatw.cf
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2021 18:54:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db11907f271122e6d9b63500dc3823f511610823264; expires=Mon, 15-Feb-21 18:54:24 GMT; path=/; doma
in=.ifatw.cf; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://ifatw.cf/
CF-Cache-Status: BYPASS
cf-request-id: 07ae25815d000030cec2834000000001
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=6L9ueuFJlc%2B4h4%2BHbwAJsHWLx4GhA52swISDg
IUYNjVH3O6Wd2yrRNCzsMatDQLF86HjdNYxLrOWX1JEMKuLq%2BhDKiDNcHhOqQ%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 612a0b7bcd9f30ce-ORD
```

Comment: I use curl to help debug redirect problems by looking at the returned headers. Try `curl -I URL`. If the URL is redirecting, there will be an HTTP `Location` header with the new location. Repeat following the new location. After several redirects, most web browsers will report an error. A well designed website will redirect once to the desired final URL.

Comment: I did that, check out my edited question. I added the result.

Comment: I get an identical result as I do for my other websites.

Comment: The client makes a request to `http://ifatw.cf` and is redirected to `https://ifatw.cf/`. That redirect  is fine. Now repeat using the new location.  Too many redirects and browsers will report an error.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ww9o42   here

Comment: You did not use the exact value of the Location header as shown in your screenshot.

Comment: What do you mean I didn't? I did, I just didn't use the '/' at the end.

Comment: The slash `/` make a difference as that is a different URL. Think like a computer. `xxx` is not the same as `xxx/`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/wwflb1    here you go

Comment: I am trying to help you but you need to put on your "thinking hat". You are receiving the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. This means that you started with a URL that redirected. The browser followed that redirect and was redirected again. This repeated until the browser gave up. Start debugging with the original URL and figure it out. You do not need to post each step of the way. Post once you know the problem and the solution.

Comment: Well, I don't get that error. I get it in a specific situation which I explained above. The main issue is (which you can see if you go to the website) a lack of images in Chrome and a lack of SSL certificate in Firefox. And I don't know why.

Comment: You can use curl to debug issues with images also. Another tool to learn how to use is the Chrome or Firefox debuggers. They will also display errors accessing resources.

Comment: Do you actually know how to migrate WordPress? I mean that actual steps required and not guessing on what needs to be done. For example, the MySQL database has URLs for resources. Files need certain permissions and ownership. Did you update those rows with the new domain name? I have a feeling that you have much more serious problems. There are a few good documents on migrating Apache, WordPress and MySQL.

Comment: I've used a wordpress plugin called All in one Wp migration, and did this with 3 more websites which work fine. I think this is the issue here: http://prntscr.com/wwjgho for some reason it uses IP address from the GCP, and not my domain.

Comment: Using IP addresses for WordPress is not good. However, if the domain points to the IP address, then that is not your problem displaying images or with redirects. Just one more item to clean up. "All in One" is a nice product. However, it does not manage Apache, .htaccess or MySQL. Only backing up and restoring WordPress. The fact that you migrated three other sites and they "appear" to work correctly is not science, that is assuming without validation.